# How does k8 traffic flow internally?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have ingress and service with LB. When traffic coming from outside it hits ingress first and then does it goes to pods directly using ingress LB or it goes to service and get the pod ip via selector and then goes to pods? If it's first way, what is the use of services? And which kind, services or ingress uses readinessProbe in the deployment?

All the setup is in GCP

I am new to K8 networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service type `LoadBalancer` is a external source provided by your cloud and are NOT in Kubernetes cluster. They can work forwarding the request to your pods using node selector, but you can't for example make path rules or redirect, rewrites because this is provided by an Ingress.

> **Service** is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them (sometimes this pattern is called a micro-service). The set of Pods targeted by a Service is usually determined by a selector (see below for why you might want a Service without a selector).

```
        Internet
            |
     [ LoadBalancer ]
       --|-----|--
       [ Services ]
       --|      |--
    [ Pod1 ]  [ Pod2 ]
```

When you use **Ingress**, is a *component* controller by a ingress controller that is basically a pod configured to handle the rules you defined. 
To use ingress you need to configure a service for your path, and then this service will reach the pods with configures selectors. You can configure some rules based on path, hostname and them redirect for the service you want. Like this:

```
        Internet
            |
       [ Ingress ]
       --|-----|--
       [ Services ]
       --|      |--
    [ Pod1 ]  [ Pod2 ]
```

> **Ingress** exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

[This article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0) has a good explanation between all ways to expose your service.

The [**readnessProbe**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) is configured in your pod/deployment specs, and **kubelet** is responsible to evaluate your container healthy.

> The kubelet uses readiness probes to know when a Container is ready to start accepting traffic. A Pod is considered ready when all of its Containers are ready. One use of this signal is to control which Pods are used as backends for Services. When a Pod is not ready, it is removed from Service load balancers.

[kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-proxy) is the responsible to foward the request for the pods.

For example, if you have 2 pods in different nodes, kube-proxy will handle the firewall rules (iptables) and distribute the traffic between your nodes. Each node in your cluster has a kube-proxy running.

kube-proxy can be configured in 3 ways: [userspace mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace), [iptables mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables) and [ipvs mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs).

> If kube-proxy is running in iptables mode and the first Pod that’s selected does not respond, the connection fails. This is different from userspace mode: in that scenario, kube-proxy would detect that the connection to the first Pod had failed and would automatically retry with a different backend Pod.

**References:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: In second case, does service(nodeport) balance the load across the pods? or else how traffic is served across pods?

Comment: [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-proxy) is the responsible to handle this requests. For example, if you have 2 pods in different nodes, kube-proxy will handle the firewall rules (iptables) and distribute the traffic between your nodes. Each node in your cluster has a kube-proxy running.

Comment: So kube-proxy knows, if one pod is busy, will it pass the traffic to other pods in other nodes? Or else which node's kube-proxy is free will pick the request? Basic question is, Is kube-proxy pull or push mechanism?

Comment: It's depends of what kube-proxy config you are using. If kube-proxy is running in iptables mode and the first Pod that’s selected does not respond, the connection fails. This is different from userspace mode. I've update my answer with this information.

Answer (score 2):

Depends whether your LoadBalancer service exposes the Ingress controller or your application Pods (the first is the correct approach).

The usual way to use Services and Ingresses is like this:

```
LoadBalancer Service -> Ingress -> ClusterIP Service -> Pods
```

In that case, the traffic from the Internet first hits the load balancer of your cloud provider (created by the LoadBalancer Service), which forwards it to the Ingress controller (which is one or multiple Pods running NGINX in your cluster), which in turn forward it to your application Pods (by getting the Pods' IP addresses from the ClusterIP Service).

I'm not sure if you currently have this constellation:

```
Ingress -> LoadBalancer Service -> Pods
```

In that case, you don't need a LoadBalancer Service there. You need only a ClusterIP Service behind an Ingress, and then you typically expose the Ingress with a LoadBalancer Service.

Comment: I am using Second method. I guess GCP ingress does not support ClusterIp for some reason. So Nodeport and LB are only options. And as @KoopaKiller say's in comment below answer kube-proxy will distribute the load. The basic difference between Lb and NodePort is LB has standard IP but  in case of NodePort, if Node fails, the IP change? Am i right here?